# Terminal profile text antialiasing option ignored after initial window

Tags: macos, terminal, big-sur

I'm having a strange issue with Terminal profiles that I can't seem to get to the bottom of.

For some reason the 'Antialias text' option is only being observed for the initial Terminal window. So if I quit Terminal entirely and open it again, the first window has no antialiasing on the text as I have the 'Antialias text' checkbox unticked. However, if I create a new window or tab the text is antialiased.

[image: Screenshot]

*Top: Initial window with correct rendering. Bottom: New window with antialiasing option ignored.*

If I keep both windows open and toggle Antialias text on and off only the initial window changes. If I change the text colour, both windows change.

## What I've Tried

- Removed everything from my `.bash_profile` including my custom PS1
- Switched the shell back to `zsh`
- Reset all the profiles and only changed the default profile to Pro

None of these had any effect.

I don't recall having this issue on my previous MacBook Pro on Catalina and I'm quite confident I would have noticed. I think it's possibly a bug that's been introduced on Big Sur.

Comment: In Terminal general preferences, is "On startup, open..." and "New windows open with..." set to the same profile?

Comment: Yep. I've even tested editing the profile with both windows open and monitoring the difference. Both windows definitely using the same profile.

Answer (score -1):

Not really an answer, but I saw the same issue and I'd really like to fix it. For me, it is less predictable, and I see additional strangeness. It seems to be related to external monitors.

Example:
Moving to the native MacBook Air display cleans it up.  Moving from an external monitor to another external makes the original clean window antialiased. Sometimes even the new/fresh window doesn't come up clean (sometimes it does.)

Comment: Thanks for replying mtntrx. The external monitor point is an interesting one. I'm running in clamshell mode so I've not tested on the retina display. I wonder if (assume) Apple has fudged something somewhere.

If it helps you, I've switched to iTerm2 for my Terminal now and it doesn't face the same issues. Additionally it seems a lot better anyway!